# Eclipse API: How to schedule a job that joins with another recently scheduled job?

Tags: multithreading, join, eclipse-plugin

More specifically, how do I create an IResource and then immediately delete an IResource that was created within the first IResource?

I am creating an IProject, and the Eclipse API automatically creates a ".project" IFile within the IProject. I want to delete the ".project" file that is inside the recently created IProject. Here's is my attempt, to give an idea:

```java
project.create(null);

// Remove the .project file that was created with the IProject.
// Do I need a separate thread here, that waits until the project
// has been created?
IResource file = project.findMember(".project");
file.delete(false, null);
```

I believe that I am running into a race condition, correct? I think the solution would be to have `findMember` and `delete` methods wait until my project has been created (ie I want `findMember` and `delete` to "join" with the thread invoked by `create`). Is this the right approach?

**Extra information**

If interested, and to provide some context, this question is related to my efforts in the open source project [Solstice](https://bitbucket.org/kivancmuslu/solstice/wiki/Home). Specifically, I am addressing this [issue](https://bitbucket.org/kivancmuslu/solstice/issue/134/re-implement-the-generation-of) where we are replicating the developer's workspace in real time. I am working on the ResourceSynchronizer that receives messages about changes in the developer's workspace and replicates those changes in the copy workspace. Thus, it receives a message to add an IProject, and then it receives another message to add the corresponding ".project". Since the IProject addition automatically adds the ".project", I am trying to remove the ".project" immediately after adding the IProject. If I try to add an ".project" when it already exists, a warning is generated. Thus, I am trying to avoid this warning.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you plan on supplying another .project file or do you want to permanently delete the .project file?

Comment: The .project file needs to be there if it's going to be treated as a project by the workspace. Why are you trying to remove it?

Comment: Yes, I will be supplying another .project file at another point. Thus, I want to delete the .project file that is automatically created with the IProject. I think the problem is that when I delete the .project file, I want to make sure that the IProject actually exists.

Comment: There are APIs to manipulate the .project file, you should be using those. What exactly do you want to do to the .project file?

Comment: Hopefully the update to the OP should explain my intentions. Do you have any suggestions about which API can manipulate the .project file? I am still learning how to navigate through the Eclipse API :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to the original post is below, which schedules a job to create an `IProject`, then joins and schedules another job to delete the `.project`. From what I have learned, this works because when Eclipse creates a new project, it does the following:

- It creates the top-level directory for the project,
- fires an ADDED event for the project.
- It creates a .project file inside the project folder,
- fires an ADDED event for the .project file.

```java
// Create "FamilyMember" so each job will be recognized as being in the
// same "family". In this case, use the same "lastName".
private class FamilyMember extends Job
{
    private String lastName;

    public FamilyMember(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        super(firstName + " " + lastName);
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    protected IStatus run(@Nullable IProgressMonitor monitor)
    {
        // Take care of family business
        return Status.OK_STATUS;
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean belongsTo(Object family) {
        return lastName.equals(family);
   }
}
```

In another method, do the following:

```
final IProject project = (IProject) resource; // Project to be created.

// Need to create a project that does not have a .project file.
// To do so, create a project, then delete its .project file.
Job createProjectJob = new FamilyMember("Create", "SyncProject")
{
    @Override
    protected IStatus run(@Nullable IProgressMonitor monitor)
    {
        try
        {
            ResourceUtility.createProject(project);
        }
        catch (CoreException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Status.OK_STATUS;
    }
};

// This job deletes the .project file from the final project defined above.
Job deleteProjectFileJob = new FamilyMember("Delete", "SyncProject")
{
    @Override
    protected IStatus run(@Nullable IProgressMonitor monitor)
    {
        try
        {
            project.findMember(".project").delete(false, null);
        }
        catch (CoreException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Status.OK_STATUS;
    }
};

// Schedule and join the jobs.
IJobManager manager = Job.getJobManager();
createProjectJob.schedule();
try
{
    manager.join("SyncProject", null);
    deleteProjectFileJob.schedule();
}
catch (OperationCanceledException | InterruptedException e)
{
    SolsticeClient.getLogger().logWarning("Exception during project without .project creation: "
                                              + e);
}
```

The following links were also used:

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Concurrency/jobs-api.html

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/ntopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/jobs/IJobManager.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have an existing `.project` file you can use it to create the project like this:

```java
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();

// Read the existing project file - this does not have to be in the workspace

IPath path = new Path(existingProjectFile); 

IProjectDescription projectDesc = workspace.loadProjectDescription(path);

// Make sure project location is the default in the workspace

projectDesc.setLocation(null);

// Create 'handle' to project

IProject project = workspace.getRoot().getProject(projectName);

// Create the project using the existing description data

project.create(projectDesc, progress monitor);
```

The `project.create` should really be done in a `WorkspaceModifyOperation`.

Comment: This is useful information, except it does not apply to my situation. It would be very useful to create an `IProject` from a `.project` that does NOT already exist. To do so, I need to obtain the `IProjectDescription` without needing an `IPath` to an EXISTING `.project` file. According to the Eclipse API, the `workspace.loadProjectDescription(path)` above requires `path` "to be in the local file system of an existing project description file". So, is there another way to create an IProject given a non-existing `.project`?

Comment: The `.project` file does not have to be in the workspace. This is the code used by Import Existing Project.